# Pig frontend set custom classpath on Oozie

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

Hello Pig/Oozie Guru's

I have implemented a custom Loader which extends LoadFunc . I am using some external dependencies in the constructor of that Loader. I am able to set the classpath on Pig frontend and get my task working standalone. However I am not sure how to set the Pig Frontend classpath on Oozie ? Anyone have any experience solving similar issue ?

Appreciate any hints.

Here is how I ran standalone

```
for j in $LIBDIR/*.jar
do
  LIBJARS=$LIBJARS,$j
  HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$j
done

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

pig -cp /local_path_to_jar/xx.jar -Dmapreduce.job.classloader=true query.pig
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by below settings

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.classloader</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Reference:

http://jaikit.blogspot.com/2014/12/precedence-to-user-classpathlibraries.html